# Query the price of a candle in real time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

What possibility is there to query the price of a candle in real time and compare it with a variable. I want that when the price of the candle has reached the price of my long or short trade without it being closed, it will be canceled. Is that possible? I tried that, it works, the candle price is displayed in real time, but how can I now trigger a trading view alarm to close the trade?

```
aktuell_price = close
xt := label.new(bar_index, y=high, text=str.tostring(aktuell_price), color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down)
label.delete(xt[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in real time mode on PineScript, as the your script will be executed each time the value of the asset change.
You should also use Pinescript Version 5 :

```
// Here 'close' is the value of the real-time bar during it's formation
if close > my_price 
    // It is just an example, you can use strategy.close(...) also
    strategy.cancel_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, the strategy in Pinescript does not work with the strategy calls in Tradingview. So

if(short_condition and barstate.isconfirmed and time_is_allowed) // short_condition //and big_candle > hearts_h
alertShortEntry = input.string("Entry Short {{ticker}}!", "Alert Message Short Entry: ", group = "Alert Settings")
strategy.entry("GS", strategy.short, alert_message = alertShortEntry)

work but all other calls to trigger an alarm are ignored by tradingview. So only if I specify strategy.long or strategy.short does Tradingview trigger an alarm. When I try strategy.close or strategy.exit nothing is thrown from tradingview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).